# How to correctly train VGG16 Keras

Tags: keras, vgg-net

I'm trying to retrain VGG16 to classify Lego images. However, my model has a low accuracy (between 20%). What am I doing wrong? Maybe the number of FC is wrong, or my ImageDataGenerator. I have approx. 2k images per class and a total of 6 classes.

How I create the model:

```
def vgg16Model(self,image_shape,num_classes):
    model_VGG16 = VGG16(include_top = False, weights = None)
    model_input = Input(shape = image_shape, name = 'input_layer')
    output_VGG16_conv = model_VGG16(model_input)
    #Init of FC layers
    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output_VGG16_conv)
    x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', name = 'fc1')(x)
    output_layer = Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax',name='output_layer')(x)
    vgg16 = Model(inputs = model_input, outputs = output_layer)
    vgg16.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    vgg16.summary()
    return vgg16
```

I'm creating ImageDataGenerator and training:

```
path = "real_Legos_images/trainable_classes"
evaluate_path = "real_Legos_images/evaluation"
NN = NeuralNetwork()
gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40, width_shift_range=0.02, shear_range=0.02,height_shift_range=0.02, horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path)), 
                target_size = (224,224), color_mode = "rgb", batch_size = 16, class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(evaluate_path)),
                target_size = (224,224), color_mode = "rgb", batch_size = 16, class_mode='categorical')

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
num_classes = len(os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path))))
VGG16 = NN.vgg16Model((224, 224, 3), num_classes)

VGG16.save_weights('weights.h5')
VGG16.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data = validation_generator, validation_steps = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size,
                steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, epochs = 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `VGG16` model with the parameter `include_top = False` will return 512 dimensions feature maps. Usually, we should add a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` or `GlobalMaxPooling2D` layer after it first, then flat it to an one-dimensional array. Otherwise, you will get an array which is too long to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the weight property to 'None' for VGG which means your networks is initialized with random weights. This means you are not using the pre-trained weights. So, I would suggest to try setting the weights to 'imagenet' such that you can use the VGG networks that its weights are pretrained on imagenet dataset:

```
model_VGG16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

Comment: That was intentional, I want to train the net into a whole different domain dataset, and I really don't need the pre-trained weights

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I see. But, I would suggest to set the weights to imagenet and set the trainable of the layers taken from VGG16 to false. Classify your data with the features extracted by such network and see if you get any better accuracy. VGG may still give excellent accuracy on completely different image datasets.